Free Theorem for $x \to x \to x$
I'm currently working through Philip Wadler's excellent Theorem's for free! paper[1] and trying out some basic function examples to see what free theorems we generate.
As an example, suppose we have a function of type $f : \forall A. A \to A$. The free theorem we get is
$$\forall A, B : \mathrm{Type}. \forall g: A \to B. \forall a: A. g(f_A(a)) = f_B (g(a))$$
or, stated more simply,
$$\forall A, B : \mathrm{Type}. \forall g: A \to B. g \circ f_A = f_B \circ g$$
I want to prove that $f$ must be the identity function on any type $A$.[2] That is, I want to prove that, for all types $A$ and all $a: A$, $f(a) = a$. So let $A$ be an arbitrary type and assume $a: A$. Then define $g : A \to A$ as the constant function which maps every input to $a$. The free theorem tells us $g \circ f_A = f_A \circ g$. Since $g$ is the constant function on $a$, this implies
$$a = f_A(a)$$
which was to be shown.
Now where I'm running into some problems is when I try to do the same trick with $f : \forall A. A \to A \to A$. Intuitively, it looks like there are only two possible functions $f$ with this type ($f(x, y) = x$ and $f(x, y) = y$), and I'd like to prove that. The free theorem on the type $\forall A. A \to A$ tells us that
$$\forall A, B : \mathrm{Type}. \forall g: A \to B. \forall a, a': A. g(f_A(a, a')) = f_B(g(a), g(a'))$$
I can apply the same trick (let $g$ be a constant function that maps to some arbitrary value $a : A$) and conclude that, for all $a: A$, $f_A(a, a) = a$.
If we assume $x, y: A$ with $x \neq y$ and define $g : A \to A$ such that $g(x) = x$ and $g(w) = y$ for all $w \neq x$, then the free theorem tells us that
$$\forall a, a': A. g(f_A(a, a')) = f_A(g(a), g(a'))$$
Let $a = x$ and $a' = y$. Then
$$g(f_A(x, y)) = f_A(x, y)$$
where the image of $g$ is $\{x, y\}$, so we can safely conclude that $f_A(x, y)$ must always be either $x$ or $y$, for all $A, x, y$.
But I'm struggling to conclude anything else from this statement. Specifically, I want to prove that $f$ must either always select its first argument or always select its second, but all I can show is that, for any specific inputs, $f_A(x, y)$ is either $x$ or $y$.

[1] https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/831/burton/Notes/July14/free.pdf
[2] I'm currently assuming that we don't have $\mathrm{fix} : \forall A. (A \to A) \to A$ and hence don't have to worry about $\bot$ values. I realize that, with $\bot$, there are actually multiple functions of type $\forall A. A \to A$.

What if you pick $A = \mathsf{Bool}$ and take $B$ to be arbitrary, with two values $x$ and $y$?

@DanDoel Aha! That's the piece I was missing! I figured it would be easy once someone pointed out the right values for $A$ and $B$. Thanks a ton!

One note: in some ways talking about $\mathsf{Bool}$ is cheating, because the encoding in System F is exactly the type you're asking about, and if you're assuming there are exactly two booleans, you're assuming what you're trying to prove. But, it's still possible to prove, at least using full parametricity, if not the free theorem.
